# Couldn't checkout branch. Revision not found

Tags: android, android-studio, github, gitlab, git-branch

I have an android app that I'm working on, the app has three branches `master`, `design` and `functionality`. When I yesterday stopped working everything was fine. Now when I started again it gave me to add all the files from the `Design` branch which are already there on a private repository on GitLab. So because of that I checked on the `Functionality` branch. Now when I want to checkout back to the `Design` branch it says

> Couldn't checkout Design: Revision not found in "ProjectName"

Basically I can not work with the `Design` branch.

Did someone knows how can I fix this.

What  I tried to do is to create a new local branch from the remote `origin/Design` but that didn't work as well.

Comment: first thing: you are talking about `Design` and `design` as well as `Functionality` and `functionality` - is it upper or lower case letters - that might matter.

second thing: did you try a `git fetch -a` and `git branch -l` afterwards? Are your branches visible in the list? Can you now do a `git checkout <branch name>`?

Comment: I work in Android Studio. First checked out `dev` branch, then tried to create a new branch (in the bottom right corner of the IDE) and got this error. Then I created the new branch again, and now this error has disappeared.

Comment: the error with me was, i was trying to checkout  a branch while branch was not created yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
git fetch -a
```

and then

```
git checkout <branch name>
```

worked in my scenario

I think this should work